# Append Random Text to File (C)

Tags: c, random

I'm trying to create a file inside a directory, then append some random text inside of the file.

**My Code**

```
char dirname[30]; 
sprintf(dirname, "myroom.%d", (int)getpid()); 
mkdir(dirname,0777); 

char path[path_max+1];
snprintf(path1, PATH_MAX+1, "%s/file1.txt,dirname); 
FILE *filedir1 = fopen(path1, "a+"); 
fclose(filedir1); 

char *random_name = { "burger", "toast", "burrito", "noodles" };
int number = rand();
fputs(random_name[number], filedir1];
```

**What I want**

(*Inside directory "dirname"*)

When I open file1.txt, I expect there will be either the word burrito, burger, toast, or noodles in the first line.

**What I get**

file1.txt still empty.

**Questions**

Anybody know what happen with my code? I saw from youtube video, to append some text into a file, all I need is the fputs command but it doesn't seem to work in my code. Is it because I'm using "a+" in fopen?

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that rand() is creating problem.use rand()%4 instead.
And you are closing the file using fclose() before putting random word. Use it at last.

Comment: Hey Sourav, I've tried that but even I changed into `fputs(random_name[2], filedir1]; (which should append "burrito")` it still doesn't work

Comment: have you moved that fclose at last??

Comment: nice catch! It works now, my bad that I didn't examine carefully about the fclose().

Comment: It happens to me too. :)

Comment: Yeah. However, what about the rand()%4? Is rand() only wrong?

Comment: I think so. rand() can create any random number. may be 10000. But in your array there is 4 elements. rand()%4 will produce 0,1,2,3.

Answer (score 3):

After opening a file, you are close that file. After closing the file, you are not able to enter the text to that file.

```
FILE *filedir1 = fopen(path1, "a+"); 
fclose(filedir1);
```

Your problem is in this fclose line. You have to do this in after finishing the write operation in that file.

So, remove the fclose(filedir1) and put this line after writing the file.